# How to add a parameter in GET and do not ger Internal Server Error?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

When I added `/{index}` in Route, and `int index` as a parameter (pic1) i got an error saying (pic2). I expected showed on (pic3). What should I do?

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2-1]

[image: pic2-2]

[image: pic3]

Comment: Please post code as text, not images. Try `Get([FromRoute] int index)`

Comment: And `[Route("{index}")]` should be enough, no need for `Get/`

Answer (score 0):

Use [] instead of {} I mean :

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class NameController
{
     [HttpGet("get")] 
     public ActionResult Get(int index)
     {
     ...
     }
}
```

Comment: Never saw that syntax before. Are you sure?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: oh shit sorry you should do this:
`[Route("api/[controller]")]


    [HttpGet("get")]
public ActionResult Get(int index){...}`

Comment: you can edit your answer, just click `edit` under your post.

Answer (score 0):

Full example, since comments are already confusing ...

```
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")] // RouteAttribute needs to be on the class
public class MyController : ControllerBase // ControllerBase from Assembly Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core version 6.0.0
{
  [HttpGet("{id}")] // HttpGetAttribute for each route
  public async Task<IActionResult> GetByIdAsync([FromRoute] int id)
  {
     // magic faery dust
  }
}
```

example for GET: https://localhost:5001/api/mycontroller/42